# Text should have first letter in uppercase and remaining in lowercase for visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Currently When text is entered in the "custom label" field it will be displayed on the Downloads(name of vf page) visualforce page in upper-case.
But that should not be the case. It should start with UpperCase and remaining text should be in lowercase.

Current Scenario: GUIDE,
Expected Scenario: Guide

I am not sure how to do that...

Current VF Code snippet:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered=" {!i.ABC_Url_Image_Url__c == 'n/a'}">
<a class="text-uppercase" href=" {!i.ABC_Url__c}"> {!i.ABC_Url_Text__c}
<span class="XYZ"></span>
</a>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS would do this:

```
.text-title-case {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```